# How to print/export a series of strings to csv via Panda from a Selenium scraped loop in Python

Tags: python, pandas, selenium-webdriver

I'm a beginner with Python, using Selenium (+ chrome) and Pandas to scrape a series of strings from a website.

The code below starts by logging into a webpage, creating a list of subpages listed (all having the link name 'Detail'), looping through them, creating a sublist of pages (according to links with a euro sign in it), and looping through them to scrape a series of values (building_name, building_code and total_cost).

**Site structure**

```
Main page
    Page Detail 1
        Page €A
            building_name
            building_code
            total_cost
        Page €B
        Page €C
    Page Detail 2
        Page €A
        Page €B
        Page €C
    Page Detail 3
        Page €A
        Page €B
        Page €C
```

Where I am now stumbling is outputting these values into a single dataframe using Panda to be exported as a csv.

[screenshot of incorrect data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1Y8M.png)

As you can see, the data is incorrectly orientated (building name should read 'Bungalow'), and only has one entry, when there should be a number of them.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import re
import pandas as pd

#navigate to home page
driver.get("http://example.com")

# Wait for the new page to load after logins
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, '__layout')))

# Find all links with the text 'Detail'
detail_links = [x.get_attribute('href') for x in driver.find_elements(By.LINK_TEXT, 'Detail')]

for url in detail_links:
    driver.get(url)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, '__layout')))
    
    # Find all the links that have a euro sign in their accompanying text label
    euro_links = [x.get_attribute('href') for x in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[span[contains(text(), '€')]]")]

    for url2 in euro_links:
        driver.get(url2)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, '__layout')))
        
        # Get the building cost string
        total_cost = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app"]div/span').text
        
        # Get the building name
        building_name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="app"]/li[7]/a').text

        # Get the building ID code from the url
        type_url = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="app"]/li[7]/a').get_attribute("href")
        try:
            building_code = re.search('=(.+?)&', type_url).group(1)
        except AttributeError:
            # AAA, ZZZ not found in the original string
            building_code = ''  # apply your error handling

        # Output the building name, code and total cost to a row in a panda dataframe
        df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(building_name, building_code, total_cost)), columns=['Name', 'Code', 'Total Costs'])

print(df)

driver.quit()
```

I have tried using csv but I think pandas is a lot easier to work with.

Can anyone help me with outputting these looped text strings correctly into a pandas dataframe and export them as a csv?

Comment: Please add an [mre].

Comment: I've edited down the code to be more concise

Answer (score 0):

Without an url it is a bit harder to give an exact answer, but let me show up the following issue. Main issue is that you overwrite your dataframe in each iteration, that is why you just get a single result.

Better append your dataframes to a list and concat them after leaving your loop - Alternative would be to create a list of dicts and create your dataframe from there:

```
...
data = []

for url in detail_links:
    driver.get(url)
    ...    
    for url2 in euro_links:
        driver.get(url2)
        ...    
        # Output the building name, code and total cost to a row in a panda dataframe
        data.append(pd.DataFrame(list(type_name, type_code, bouwkosten_total), columns=['Name', 'Code', 'Total Costs']))

print(pd.concat(data, ignore_index=True))
```

---

Alternative is to store `dicts` instead of `dataframes`:

```
...
data = []

for url in detail_links:
    driver.get(url)
    ...    
    for url2 in euro_links:
        driver.get(url2)
        ...    
        
        data.append({
            'Name':type_name,
            'Code':type_code,
            'Total':bouwkosten_total
        })
print(pd.DataFrame(data))
```

Comment: Hi Hedgehog, thanks for responding.
With your suggestions, I get the error 'ValueError: No objects to concatenate' - do I need to define the dataframe before the url2 loop, and how do I create a dataframe with variables I haven't defined yet? Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: As mentioned, with an URL it would probably be a bit more easier to give appropriate help. no, no dataframe has to be created in advance, this is done using `data.append(pd.DataFrame(list(type_name, type_code, bouwkosten_total), columns=['Name', 'Code', 'Total Costs']))` and exactly this point would have to be extended if new columns / variables are added.

Comment: Unfortunately I can’t share the site i’m working on. Would you be able to give me pointers in defining the date frame? I’ll see if i can set up a comparable scenario on a public site tomorrow.

Comment: `data.append([type_name, type_code, bouwkosten_total])` ...within the loop
`df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Code', 'Building Cost Total'])` ...and defining the dataframe's column headings outside seems to work - so without concat

Comment: Yes, this also works and there are other options, it depends on how you want to proceed and what your goal is. The result is identically a `dataframe` either from a list of lists or from a list of dataframes. Think using `dicts` or `dataframes` is a bit cleaner, because you define data and headers in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon the other answer - this code works

```
...
data = []

for url in detail_links:
    driver.get(url)
    ...    
    for url2 in euro_links:
        driver.get(url2)
        ...    
        # Output the building name, code and total cost to a row in a panda dataframe
        data.append([type_name, type_code, bouwkosten_total])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Code', 'Building Cost Total'])
print(data)
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False, header=True)
```

Comment: Please check your example, it will endup in an error because data missmatches with columns. One reason why I would define both in one go or place.

Comment: data.append([type_name, type_code, bouwkosten_total])